# Bevy - Render to wgpu::Texture

Tags: rust, bevy, wgpu-rs, webgpu, web-sys

I am looking for an elegant and hopefully bevy-esque way of rendering to a `wgpu::Texture`. The reason is that I'm am implementing a `WebXR` libary and the `WebXRFramebuffer` must be rendered to in immersive XR.

```rs
let framebuffer = //get framebuffer from web_sys
let texture: wgpu::Texture = unsafe {
        device.create_texture_from_hal::<wgpu_hal::gles::Api>(
            wgpu_hal::gles::Texture {
                inner: wgpu_hal::gles::TextureInner::ExternalFramebuffer {
                    inner: framebuffer,
...
```

My question is, once I have created this `wgpu::Texture` is there a way to either:

1. Set it as the main pass texture of the bevy engine
2. Render the cameras to a `bevy::Image` and blit that to the `wgpu::texture`

I've seen examples like the [superconductor engine](https://github.com/MeetKai/superconductor/blob/3ed64c119e5e7419752e5602fe5d8868d5e503cf/src/systems/rendering.rs#L235) doing a lot of low level wgpu work to achieve this but it feels like there should be a simpler way with recent bevy features like the render graph and camera render targets.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering to a `TextureView` is supported as of Bevy `0.11`, see the [pr](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/pull/8042) for more info.

here's an exerpt from my `web_xr` crate that sets the `TextureView` from a `gl_layer`
as a target that cameras can render to. Look [here](https://github.com/mrchantey/forky/blob/dc514e8e9de6c1edc6b1c7159d848239362cd7d9/crates/bevy_webxr/src/bevy_utils/_camera/create_views.rs#L38) for creating the camera and [here](https://github.com/mrchantey/forky/blob/dc514e8e9de6c1edc6b1c7159d848239362cd7d9/crates/bevy_webxr/src/bevy_utils/_camera/update_manual_texture_views.rs#L6) for applying the texture view.

```rs
/// set the texture view in camera
...
let mut entity = commands.spawn(Camera3dBundle {
            camera_3d: Camera3d {
                clear_color, //split screen
                ..default()
            },
            camera: Camera {
                order,
                target: RenderTarget::TextureView(**texture_id),
                viewport: Some(xr_camera.viewport.clone()),
                ..default()
            },
            transform: pose.into(),
            ..default()
        });
}

/// updating the texture view
pub fn update_manual_texture_views(
    gl_layer: NonSend<web_sys::XrWebGlLayer>,
    render_device: Res<RenderDevice>,
    texture_id: Res<bevy_utils::FramebufferTextureViewId>,
    mut manual_tex_view: ResMut<ManualTextureViews>,
) {
    let dest_texture = xr_utils::create_framebuffer_texture(
        render_device.wgpu_device(),
        &gl_layer,
    );

    let size =
        UVec2::new(gl_layer.framebuffer_width(), gl_layer.framebuffer_height());

    let descriptor = wgpu::TextureViewDescriptor::default();
    let view = dest_texture.create_view(&descriptor);

    manual_tex_view.insert(
        **texture_id,
        ManualTextureView::with_default_format(view.into(), size),
    );
}
```